# how to iterate a linkedhashset starting from a specific element in java?

Tags: java

I have a linkedhashset containing these names
[Raj,Anusha,Suresh,Sashant,Tisha,Prajyoti,Shubhavi,Daniel]
I want to iterate this linkedhashset starting from Sashant to Daniel.

```
String item1;
for (String key : list1) {
item1 = key;
System.out.println(item1);
}
```

The above code prints all the names from the linkedhashset. How do i print from a specific name (from Suresh to Daniel)? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with the data structure you are trying to use. Under the hood, a doubly-linked list is used to iterate through the list which does not explicitly allow you to jump to an index.

Suggestions (in order of preference):

1. Use a different data structure if you can
2. You can iterate through the list as you currently are but only start printing names once you come across the first name you're looking for

An example of what 2 may look like:

```
String firstNameToPrint = "Some Name";
boolean foundFirstNameToPrint = false;
for (String key : list1) {
    if (key.equals(firstNameToPrint) {
        foundFirstNameToPrint = true;
    }
    if (foundFirstNameToPrint) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to implement the 2nd preference that you suggested? using same data structure

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to iterate the elements in chronological order of their insertion into hashset, you may try the data structure consisting of a hashset and List.
Whenever you add a String into hashset, you add it into List as the last element. That takes constant time.
Whenever you remove a String from hashset, you remove it from List as well. That takes linear time.
And whenever you want to iterate from specific element, you use indexOf(String s) to find the index and start iterating from that index.